# Can i pass <sup> tag in Open Graph description for Facebook

Tags: facebook-opengraph

I am passing a description to FB like button by OpenGraph description metatag.
In description it is mandatory to pass R-Ball (®) in super script <sup>.</sup>

Can i pass HTML tags with CSS too in Opengraph Description tag?

I want to achieve in FB description:

```
COMPANY NAME <sup style='font-size:80%'>&reg;</sup>
```

COMPANY NAME ®

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass HTML tags in Open Graph tags. However, you can use ® (the actual character, not the escape code) in the Open Graph description. It won't be super script, but at least it's something.